# Certain Keys on Keyboard won't work (not even via on-screen Keyboard)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

So i recently spilled some beer on my keyboard and i noticed that the "T" key stopped working.  So I swapped it out with a new keyboard but now the problem persists?   But about 10 minutes after i restart the computer.  it works for a little bit, hence this post.  But soon it will stop, and not even the "On-Screen Keyboard" will register the "T" key.

I am running Windows 7 and really have no idea what is going on.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: I am this is a software problem, despite the spilled beer (tragedy.. =/) I am only saying this because the On-Screen Keyboard won't work as well. You haven't installed any new software lately, or accidently changed keyboard layouts (despite it only being one key), or anything else lately have you?

Comment: I think your computer is telling you that you should be a T-totaler.

Comment: Can we rule out a software issue by trying a livecd? Is this a desktop or laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (in my case, the button with the ! does not work (on a swiss german keyboard)).

I tried to detect the problem with AutoHotKey (I could not see the button or who influences it neither) and KeyTweak (did also not work).

The current workaround: set up a hot key via AutoHotKey that inserts the button ! via the clipboard (the Send function of AutoHotKey also does not work). Save the following in the file exclamationMark.ahk and run the script via AutoHotKey:

```
; workaround to make "!" available via AltGr-5

<^>!5::

 ; Save the entire clipboard to a variable of your choice.

ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   

Clipboard:="!"
;Send ^v      ; does not work in cygwin mintty terminal
Send +{Ins}

Clipboard := ClipSaved   ; Restore the original clipboard. Note the use of Clipboard (not ClipboardAll).
ClipSaved =   ; Free the memory in case the clipboard was very large.
return
```